# Getting an error "the constructor file(string) is not visible"

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am learning `Selenium` with `java`. Installed Selenium 3.4.0 and Firefox 54 and for firefox installed `geckodriver jar file` from the seleniumhq.org site.

I have added external Jar files of selenium standalone 3.4.0 and geckodriver to the project and create one class for java project as below:

```
package TestPackage;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File;

public class Test 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        WebDriver driver = null;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\geckodriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities().firefox();
        cap.setCapability("marionette", true);
        cap.setBrowserName("firefox");
        FirefoxProfile firefoxProfile = new FirefoxProfile();
        File pathToBinary = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
        FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver(ffBinary, firefoxProfile, cap);

        driver.get("https://www.google.co.in");
    }

}
```

In this I am getting an error as

> the constructor file(string) is not visible for line

```
File pathToBinary = new File("C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
FirefoxBinary ffBinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathToBinary);
```

Also I am not able to run my program getting below error:

> Archive for required library: 'D:/geckodriver.exe' in project 'Test'
>   cannot be read or is not a valid ZIP file

Please suggest the solution as soon as possible.

Comment: Are you using `com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File` instead of `java.io.File` on purpose?

Comment: Yes. thanks. I have removed the com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.javascript.host.file.File and included "java.io.File". error is no more.

Comment: However now I am getting an error while running the program as `"Error: Could not find or load main class TestPackage.Test"` Could please suggest solution?

Comment: @Rajshree Can you update us about your exact manual steps which you are trying to automate? Thanks